# Add substring to an Inner Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerbi, inner-join, powerquery

I want to replicate this query in my Power BI:

```sql
SELECT n.codigonotario,
       n.nombrenotario,
       CASE SUBSTRING(dc.path, 11, 4)WHEN '0001' THEN COUNT(cp.indiceunico)END AS NUM_OPERACIONES,
       CASE SUBSTRING(dc.path, 11, 4)WHEN '0001' THEN SUM(cp.bases)END AS NUM_BASES,
       SUM(dc.valornumerico / (CASE ISNULL(p.MONEDA, 0)WHEN 0 THEN 166.386 ELSE 1 END)) AS TotalCuantias,
       RTRIM(LTRIM(cp.indiceunico)) AS codigoconcepto,
       cp.textoconcepto + ' (' + RTRIM(LTRIM(cp.indiceunico)) + ')' AS DESCRIPCIONCONCEPTO,
       cdc.categoriacampo
FROM notarios n
     INNER JOIN protocolos p ON n.codigonotario = SUBSTRING(p.codigoprotocolo, 2, LEN(n.codigonotario))
     INNER JOIN conceptosprotocolos cp ON cp.codigoprotocolo = p.codigoprotocolo
     INNER JOIN datosconceptos dc ON dc.codigoprotocolo = p.codigoprotocolo
                                 AND SUBSTRING(cp.path, 6, 4) = SUBSTRING(dc.path, 6, 4)
     INNER JOIN camposdatosconceptos cdc ON cdc.codigocampodatos = dc.codigocampodatos
     INNER JOIN conceptos c ON c.codigoconcepto = cp.codigoconcepto
WHERE p.fechaprotocolo >= '01/01/2022'
  AND p.fechaprotocolo <= '31/12/2022'
  AND n.codigonotario LIKE CASE LEN('Prueba')WHEN 0 THEN '%' ELSE 'Prueba' END
  AND (cdc.categoriacampo = 'CUANTIA'
    OR cdc.categoriacampo = 'HONORARIOSBRUTO'
    OR cdc.categoriacampo = 'HONORARIOSREDUCCION')
  AND p.encargado LIKE CASE LEN('Prueba')WHEN 0 THEN '%' ELSE 'Prueba' END
  AND (p.codigoprotocolo LIKE 'p%'
    OR p.codigoprotocolo LIKE 'c%')
  AND cp.indiceunico LIKE CASE LEN(1)WHEN 0 THEN '%' ELSE 1 END
GROUP BY n.codigonotario,
         n.nombrenotario,
         cp.indiceunico,
         cp.textoconcepto,
         dc.path,
         cdc.categoriacampo;
```

I already have the database and tables imported in my project:

[image]

And I know how to implement inner joins:
[image]

But some of those inner joins need substrings and other functions, starting with the first inner join:

```
INNER JOIN protocolos p ON n.codigonotario = SUBSTRING(p.codigoprotocolo, 2, LEN(n.codigonotario))
```

You can't use SQL functions in Power BI, but you can use Power Query, so I'm struggling trying to replicate those here (it doesn't recognize 'MID' or 'LEFT').

```
let
  Origen = Sql.Databases("LAPTOP-OSCAR"),
  Far = Origen{[Name="Far"]}[Data],
  dbo_NOTARIOS = Far{[Schema="dbo",Item="NOTARIOS"]}[Data],
  #"Consultas combinadas" = Table.NestedJoin(dbo_NOTARIOS, {"CODIGONOTARIO"}, PROTOCOLOS, {"CODIGOPROTOCOLO"}, "PROTOCOLOS", JoinKind.Inner)

in
  #"Consultas combinadas"
```

Could somebody help me to replicate the substring function in Power BI, please?

Comment: I believe the Power Query function is Text.Middle

Comment: Why bother with PowerQuery when you can load the data faster with a native SQL query? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/native-database-query

Comment: Introducing the SQL query directly on that menu works great, thanks! Will use it in the future, but I'm more interested in replicating those SQL functions at the moment.